# open URL from user input or TextBox

Tags: javascript, html

i want an easy solution to download the report number on a website but the URL is complicated and the input which needs to be added is in the middle of the URL, my target url is like this: http://example.com/pocservlet?ReportNumber=USERINPUT&&IPAddress=1.1.1.1&&Method=DownloadPDF

so only 'USERINPUT' should be changed from user input

Comment: What exactly are you needing to do? A. Change the browser URI, B. Redirect the user to a new URL C. String-Replace USERINPUT in a string stored in a var with JS D. Any other? Whichis your current approach on this?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried. String concatenation is not complicated or hard to research. Also identify where you ran into problems. Stackoverflow is not a free code writing service. The objective here is for others to help you fix **your code** once you have done the basic research yourself and run into bugs or unexpected behaviors

Comment: Also using URL API makes this much less complicated also

Comment: i have tried code from here: http://www.ahfb2000.com/threads/11513-open-url-from-text-box  but as i said the changes is custom not adding in end of the url

Answer (score 1):

Just put it in the middle of the string:

```js
var userinput = prompt();
var url = "http://example.com/pocservlet?ReportNumber=" + userinput + "&IPAddress=1.1.1.1&Method=DownloadPDF";
window.open(url);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use ES6 template strings to do this.

Please note that ES6 is not supported in older browsers, or in Internet Explorer, so if you're looking to use ES6 you'll need to ensure you're using a transpiler such as Babel.

Wrap the string in back ticks instead of normal quotes and insert as ${VARIABLENAME}

Simple example:

```js
let userInput = "TEST";
const url = `http://example.com/pocservlet?ReportNumber=${userInput}&IPAddress=1.1.1.1&&Method=DownloadPDF`;

console.log(url);
```

Comment: This is an ES6 feature and so isn't compatible with Internet Explorer.

Comment: True, but perhaps it's better to look at transpiling/compiling code rather than restricting usage. There are tons of features lost by limiting this way. Just my opinion though, each to their own.

Comment: @AdamRoberts have to consider that someone who can't sort out basic concatenation most likely has no idea what transpiling even is or knows the intricacies of legacy browsers

Comment: @wizzwizz4 no need to get rid of ES6, just because of IE. You could still use a Polyfill.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 makes a good point though - edited the answer a little

Comment: @AdamRoberts If you know about Stack Snippets (there's a button on the desktop website on the edit page if you have a mouse) you can add a demo with Babel enabled.

Comment: Still pretty new here so didn't know, edited. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You're surpassing my early answers, so I think you'll do fine. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could have a String with `"USERINPUT"` inside it with which to replace with the correct user input. JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2t4gufqr/

```
var url = "http://example.com/pocservlet?ReportNumber=USERINPUT&IPAddress=1.1.1.1&Method=DownloadPDF";
var urlToOpen = url.replace("USERINPUT", document.getElementById("someInputID").value);
window.open(urlToOpen);//use window.open(urlToOpen, "_blank"); to open in new tab
```

Demo:

```html
<input type="text" id="url" placeholder="Enter report number">
<button onClick="openUrl()">Open URL</button>
<script>
var url = "http://example.com/pocservlet?ReportNumber=USERINPUT&IPAddress=1.1.1.1&Method=DownloadPDF";
function openUrl(){
    var urlToOpen = url.replace("USERINPUT", document.getElementById("url").value);
    alert(urlToOpen);
    window.open(urlToOpen);//use window.open(url, "_blank"); to open in new tab
}
</script>
```